# TensorFlow CSV input

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow

I am trying to read a CSV file (in a performant way, like recommended from Google) using the **tf.TextLineReader()**.

As you can see I can create batches that I will later use to train my very basic regression model.
The problem is that **tf.train.shuffle_batch** returns a tensor. This means that I cannot use a placeholder X in my model Y_pred = X*W+b. 
In the training phase I am now using the **batch_variable** just as a placeholder, but I need a placeholder in order to do the Test with different data.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I modified the code like suggested by Nicolas (Thanks a lot! ) but now I am getting an accuracy of 0.0 .... that's kinda akward. 
I am using the Abalone dataset (8 features and 3 classes) where I changed the (M)ale (F)emale (I)nfant results of the classification with the one-hot vectors (1,0,0) , (0,1,0)...

```
 def getPartitionedDatasets(filenames):

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    _, value = reader.read(filename_queue) # return a key and value (key is for debugging

    record_defaults = [[1.0] for _ in range(N_FEATURES+1)]
    cont = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)

    features = tf.stack([cont[1],cont[2],cont[3],cont[4],cont[5],cont[6],cont[7],cont[8]])


    label = tf.to_int32(cont[0])

    min_after_dequeue = 10 * BATCH_SIZE
    capacity = 20 * BATCH_SIZE

    data_batch, label_batch_raw = tf.train.shuffle_batch([features, label], batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                        capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    label_batch_hot = tf.one_hot(label_batch_raw,on_value=1,off_value=0, depth=3)

    return data_batch, label_batch_hot

def get_model_params():
    """Build the model parameters."""
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N_FEATURES,CLASSES]), name='weights')
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([CLASSES]), name = "bias")
    return W, b

def build_model(data_batch, label_batch_hot, w, b):
    """Use `W` and `b` to build a model based on some data and labels."""
    Y_predicted = tf.matmul(data_batch , w) + b
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label_batch_hot,
                                                logits=Y_predicted))
    return Y_predicted, cross_entropy

def get_optimizer_op(cross_entropy_op):
    """Return an optimiser associated to a cross entropy op."""
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy_op)



def run():
    train_data, train_label = getPartitionedDatasets(["ABA_Train.csv"])
    test_data, test_label   = getPartitionedDatasets(["ABA_Test.csv"])
    W,b = get_model_params();
    train_predicted, train_cross_entropy = build_model(train_data, train_label, W, b)
    optimizer = get_optimizer_op(train_cross_entropy)

    test_predicted, test_cross_entropy = build_model(test_data, test_label, W, b)

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(test_predicted, 1), tf.argmax(test_label, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for i in range(300):  # generate 10 batches
            sess.run([optimizer])
        print(sess.run(accuracy))


def main():
    run();
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: To sum it up: 
I need to pass some test data to this trained model

 Y_predicted = tf.matmul(data_batch , W) +b 
 
How can I adjust it so that I can still using the batch Samples tensors as input?

Comment: It works... I just had to make the batch_size a parameter so that I could have different sizes for Test and Train. Before I got zero because I just did the test with 1 sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to implement various methods to

- define your model parameters,
- build a model based on these parameters and on some data,
- build an optimiser based on your model.

For example you could have something like that (assuming that your train and test data are in 2 different sets of files):

```
def get_model_params():
    """Build the model parameters.""" 
    W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N_FEATURES,CLASSES]), name='weights')
    b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([CLASSES]), name = "bias")
    return W, b

def build_model(data_batch, label_batch_hot, w, b):
    """Use `W` and `b` to build a model based on some data and labels."""
    Y_predicted = tf.matmul(data_batch , W) + b
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label_batch_hot,
                                                logits=Y_predicted))
    return y_predicted, cross_entropy

def get_optimizer_op(cross_entropy_op):
    """Return an optimiser associated to a cross entropy op."""
    return tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy_op)

def run():
    data_batch, label_batch_hot = batch_generator(train_filenames)
    test_data_batch, test_label_batch_hot = batch_generator(test_filenames)
    W, b = get_model_params()
    train_predicted, train_cross_entropy = build_model(data_batch, label_batch_hot, W, b)
    optimizer = get_optimizer_op(train_cross_entropy)

    test_predicted, test_cross_entropy = build_model(test_data_batch, test_label_batch_hot, W, b)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for i in range(300): # generate 10 batches
             sess.run([optimizer])
        sess.run(test_cross_entropy)
```

Comment: OK I will need to try it.. Just one question: Why do you need the cross entropy for testing too?

Comment: I just assumed you wanted to assess the accuracy of your trained model using cross_entropy. It's obviously up to you how you want to test it.